# Java.awt.SystemTray does not display tray icon properly

Tags: java, swing, icons, awt, system-tray

A snippet of my code is below:

```
SystemTray systray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

try{
    TrayIcon trayicon = new TrayIcon(new ImageIO.read(new File("icon.png")),"I am a description");
}
catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Everything runs smoothly but the image displayed in the system tray is cut off. Only the top left portion is displayed unless I shrink down to 16x16 (from 40x40). The `icon.png` is an image file that is loaded properly (not null).  I thought that system tray icon files could be 40px?

Could someone please explain to me what's the issue here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possibilities include `TrayIcon.setImageAutoSize()` and maybe your OS (assuming Windows) is set to some kind of high-dpi display like 120 or 144 and Java doesn't adapt to that correctly.

Comment: Wow, I completely missed that function. Thanks!

Comment: I'm the type that likes to read source code so I went and found the [windows implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/awt/windows/WTrayIconPeer.java#WTrayIconPeer) of the TrayIcon.  It looks like it targets 16x16 if you don't have autosize turned on.